# Beautifulsoup filter results raise KeyError in "for i" loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, keyerror

I am trying to minimize my codes, making it more efficient. However, I got hit by this KeyError truck, which I can't figure out what went wrong. Please Help me out Chiefs, and point me why my expression is not OK? PS I am amateur level.

With these codes:

```
recommended = soup.select('table:has(font:contains("推荐主题")), '
                          'table:has(font:contains("版块主题"))')
for item in recommended:
    for i in item.select(".folder:has(a)"):
```

I will have DOM of:

```
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439294-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439293-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439292-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439290-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
```

But when I add one more line,

```
for item in recommended:
    for i in item.select(".folder:has(a)"):
        url_tail = i['href']
```

I will get this KeyError of:

```
    return self.attrs[key]
KeyError: 'href'
```

What I am trying to get out of it are the href links, Thank you all.

Comment: is it that the result of ".folder:has(a)" is not good enough to filter out the href links?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@facelessuser has explained nicely the error (+) and given my first choice selector. It looks like there may be two other [attribute = value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors) selector possibilities as plan Bs

Either:

```
[href^="thread-"]
```

Or:

```
[title="新窗口打开"]
```

Which can be used in a list comprehension such as

```
links =  [item['href'] for item in soup.select('[href^='thread-']')]
```

Your `select` may be off `item` rather than `soup`. You can always throw in the parent class if that ends up too broad a match `.folder [title="新窗口打开"]`

Answer (score 2):

`.folder:has(a)` is selecting the `td` element, as that element is the one with the class `.folder` and has a child of `a`. It is not selecting the `a` element, just checking that the element with `.folder` has a `a` element.

Something like `.folder a` is probably what you want.

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this.

> As I don't have complete HTML or Url you are hitting, I just tried to retrieve the **href**'s values from the HTML text you have pasted.

1) Import & create BeautifulSoup object »

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> 
>>> html_text = """<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439294-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
... <td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439293-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
... <td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439292-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
... <td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439290-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>"""
>>> 
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html_text, "html.parser")
>>>
>>> soup
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439294-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439293-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439292-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439290-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
>>>
```

2) Find all tds »

```
>>> tds = soup.find_all("td", class_="folder")
>>> tds
[<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439294-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>, <td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439293-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>, <td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439292-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>, <td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439290-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>]
>>>
```

3) Inspect (Just to test)»

```
>>> tds[0]
<td class="folder"><a href="thread-10439294-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a></td>
>>> 
>>> tds[0].a
<a href="thread-10439294-1-1.html" target="_blank" title="新窗口打开"><img src="images/green001/folder_new.gif"/></a>
>>> 
>>> tds[0].a.get("href")
'thread-10439294-1-1.html'
>>>
```

4) Finally, retrieve links (2 ways) »

```
>>> # Using loop
... 
>>> for td in tds:
...     print(td.a.get("href"))
... 
thread-10439294-1-1.html
thread-10439293-1-1.html
thread-10439292-1-1.html
thread-10439290-1-1.html
>>> 
>>> for td in tds:
...     print(td.a["href"])
... 
thread-10439294-1-1.html
thread-10439293-1-1.html
thread-10439292-1-1.html
thread-10439290-1-1.html
>>> 
>>>
```